# pandas - count frequency of unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How can i exclude 0.0 column showing count value of 942, display only non zero column.

input:

```
 df.groupby('WASHING CONTAINER AGENT').size()
```

output:

```
WASH - CHEMICAL
0.0     942
12.0     20
20.0      8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['WASHING CONTAINER AGENT']!=0,:].groupby('WASHING CONTAINER AGENT').size()`

Comment: OK Thanks, got it!

Comment: how can i do the same if example for all columns ? df.iloc[:,9:33] , column 9 to 33, without the need to do it column by column

Comment: `df[~df.iloc[:,9:33].eq(0).any()]`

Comment: error:
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 0.0, 12.0, 20.0 as keys in your 'groupby' first output: please try this.

```
df = df.groupby('WASHING CONTAINER AGENT').size()[lambda x: x.index > 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this be acceptable:

```
df[df['WASHING CONTAINER AGENT']>0].groupby('WASHING CONTAINER AGENT').size()
```

And for your other question, hopefully this would do the trick:

```
df[df.iloc[:, 9:33].ne(0)].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.stack()
```

Comment: how can i do the same if example for all columns ? df.iloc[:,9:33]   , column 9 to 33, without the need to do it column by column

Comment: @okl That's another question, and you might want to add desired output with sample of input.

Comment: @okl please see the edit, maybe that would suit you?

Comment: ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64